# ssh authentication with key files: server refused our key

Tags: ssh, putty

I am using PuTTY to access my ownCloud server. I can login using userID and password fine. But when I try to login using the public/private keys I generated, I get "Server refused our key" message. Here are the steps I used (https://askubuntu.com/questions/306798/trying-to-do-ssh-authentication-with-key-files-server-refused-our-key):

```
-Generated a key pair with puttygen.exe (length: 2048 bits)
-Loaded the private key in the PuTTY profile
-Entered the public key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in one line
-# chmod 700 ~/.ssh
-# chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
-Changed /etc/ssh/sshd_config so it contains AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
-# sudo service ssh restart
```

When I try this configuration, I get "Server refused our key" message and, after entering the password, I can login. But, why I am getting this message?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The problem was that there was one extra invisible character at the end of the key ion authorization_keys file. After I removed this extra character, the key was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

the key must be in ONE single line. If there are several lines, the respective carriage return must be deleted. The line must start with a blank character then "ssh-rsa" followed by another blank and then the key.

Answer (score -1):

I searched lot of tutorials and after that I found the below solution. Please follow and you will get success

Ok here is the answer guys we spend a day trying to figure this out.
We did not write this down and had to pay the price again.

When generating the private key using puttygen "DO NOT" click "Generate" just use "Save Private Key" and use that key.

Let us know if this helped you.